# Python 2: Type error "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" using pd.read() with neo.Spike2IO

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I have code to load in Spike2 .smr files and read them in Jupyter. My code was working fine 2 days ago and now, with absolutely no change on either the file that is loaded in or the code that loads it in, it is not working. The problem code is as follows...

Cell 1 Input (to show the versions of my packages):

```
import sys
print("Python version: {}\n\nPackages versions: ".format(sys.version))

# which package versions are installed?
import pip
all_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
used_packages = ["matplotlib", "neo", "numpy", "OpenElectrophy", "os", "pandas", 
             "pylab", "scipy"]
for entry in used_packages:
    for p in all_packages:
        if entry in str(p):
            print(str(p))
```

Cell 1 Output:

```
Python version: 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]

Packages versions: 
matplotlib 1.4.3
matplotlib-venn 0.11.3
neo 0.3.3
numpy 1.12.0
pycosat 0.6.1
nose 1.3.7
backports.ssl-match-hostname 3.5.0.1
pandas 0.19.2
scipy 0.15.1
```

Cell 2 Input (load in my modules):

```
import pylab
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats as st
import os
import tables
import neo
import scipy.signal as sg
from scipy import interpolate as inter
import h5py as h
import quantities as q

plt.style.use('ggplot')
pd.options.display.max_rows = 999

%matplotlib inline
```

Now, I load in the Spike2 .smr file with:

```
r = neo.Spike2IO("Rawdata/143-16/nerve.smr").read()[0]
```

and get the following type error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-f81fd520a4c5> in <module>()
----> 1 r = neo.Spike2IO("Rawdata/143-16/nerve.smr").read()[0]

/home/wolverine/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo/io/baseio.pyc in read(self, lazy, cascade, **kargs)
    107             if not cascade:
    108                 return bl
--> 109             seg = self.read_segment(lazy=lazy, cascade=cascade,  **kargs)
    110             bl.segments.append(seg)
    111             create_many_to_one_relationship(bl)

/home/wolverine/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo/io/spike2io.pyc in read_segment(self, take_ideal_sampling_rate, lazy, cascade)
    120             if channelHeader.kind in [1, 9]:
    121                 #~ print 'analogChanel'
--> 122                 anaSigs = self.readOneChannelContinuous( fid, i, header, take_ideal_sampling_rate, lazy = lazy)
    123                 #~ print 'nb sigs', len(anaSigs) , ' sizes : ',
    124                 for anaSig in anaSigs :

/home/wolverine/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo/io/spike2io.pyc in readOneChannelContinuous(self, fid, channel_num, header, take_ideal_sampling_rate, lazy)
    240 
    241         anaSigs = [ ]
--> 242         if channelHeader.unit in unit_convert:
    243             unit = pq.Quantity(1, unit_convert[channelHeader.unit] )
    244         else:

/home/wolverine/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo/io/spike2io.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
    444                 else:
    445                     l = np.fromstring(self.array[name][0], 'u1')
--> 446                 return self.array[name][1:l+1]
    447             else:
    448                 return self.array[name]

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

The "neo.Spike2IO("filename.smr") works fine, but as soon as I add the "read()[0]" part, that is when I get the TypeError. I read up on this type error and the only answers I saw were that the file could be corrupt. I deleted my local file and re-downloaded it and also downloaded another similar file just in case the master file for the other one was corrupt. I retried my code on these two new files and received the Type Error code for both. As stated before, the code was working flawlessly just two days ago and now it won't load any .smr file. I went through and updated all of my modules and pip and anaconda, all of this did not help.

[Here is a link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B12h-_0SGfoqR3dwNFZ1YWE4VGc/view) to a short sample .smr file (only 3.1 MB) that I cut for sharing purposes. It also gives the Type Error. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by further updating my modules and Anaconda itself (and all of its respective modules). Something must have reverted to an older version.

The code to update every package in Anaconda is:

```
conda update --all
```

Further help can be found [here](http://conda-test.pydata.org/docs/examples/update.html) at the Conda homepage. Shutting down, then restarting your computer can also help to ensure that all of these updates are implemented.